# Description of the convert from AAB to APK

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle, apktool, bundletool

I am needing to know about the description of the process of converting from AAB to APK. In addition, I also want to know if each tool like apk tool or bundletool does different jobs

I tried to learn about the conversion process description between AAB and APK however it is still limited and generic, so I need someone to explain or give me a specific document about the transition between AAB and APK

Comment: If you want the specifics, why not just dig in the code, it's open source.